# In Grails, how do I tell if an object is transient or not?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a piece of code in Grails:

```
def product = Product.get(5) ?: new Product()
product.isDiscounted = product.isDiscounted ?: true
```

Problem is, if the `isDiscounted` property is already set for an existing product and it's false, I'll end up changing it to true. Is it possible to check if an object is transient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case make the property `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, then the initial value will be `null` and not default to `false`. This will help validation too, since you can verify that a choice of `false` was intentional, and not just allowing the default value.

In general though you can use the `isAttached()` method (or the property style variant `attached`), e.g.

```
def product = Product.get(5) ?: new Product()
product.isDiscounted = product.attached ? product.isDiscounted ? true
```

This case can actually be even more compactly done with a default value in the constructor:

```
def product = Product.get(5) ?: new Product(discounted: true)
```

Comment: Thanks Burt. I'm coming from a C# background so I didn't realize that `Boolean` is different from `boolean` in Java. In C#, both are the same, and a nullable type is declared by using a question mark after the type: `bool?`